# Как совмещать в одном слове «по-» и «-то»?

Tags: орфография, словообразование, приставка, дефис, частицы

Есть такое разговорное слово: по-хорошему-то.

Например: *Он поймал её, но по-хорошему-то стоило отпустить.*

Действительно ли при написании подобных выражений получается слово с двумя дефисами?

Comment: Отличный вопрос!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Судя по книжкам, так и получается, при всей непривычности слова на вид:

> *Вот как будет **по-хорошему-то**, а не по-худому.*
>
> (Н. Мещеряков, Сон под Новый год, Семидесятники: избранные
>   произведения, 1935)

Answer (score 2):

Очень хорошо можно совмещать — получается разговорное слово с двумя дефисами:
по-хорошему-то, по-плохому-то, по-честному-то, по-моему-то.

**-то**
Словообразовательная единица (постфикс). Отделяется от мотивирующего слова дефисом. Употребляется при подчёркивании или смысловом (интонационном) выделении слова, к которому относится.

*— Но, **по-честному-то**, у нас профессиональное сообщество в печальном виде существует, оно никак не оформлено, мало предметных или межпредметных ассоциаций, которые имели бы экспертный вес* (из интервью; журнал для учителей словесности "Литература").

*— А как же по-вашему?

— Вот **по-моему-то** и нужна смелость! — внушительно ответил на это Мустафетов.*
(А. Апраксин. Три плута)

P. S.  Первоначально Ваш вопрос звучал так: *Как совмещать частицы по- и -то?*
Я его исправила, потому что **по-** — это [приставка](https://orfogrammka.ru/%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%8F/%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%81_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D0%BE_%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%8F_%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%83_%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83_%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8_%D1%86%D0%BA%D0%B8_%D1%8C%D0%B8/).