# Используется ли дефис в слове, где уже есть дефис?

Tags: дефис

Допустим, есть слово *биткойн-кошелёк*. Его я с уверенностью могу написать через дефис. Но вот если я, например, захочу добавить ещё *то* – будет ли всё это через дефис? Просто я будто вообще ни разу не видел на письме подобных случаев, и поэтому не знаю, что делать. Да и слово *биткойн-кошелёк-то* выглядит слишком уж странно с тремя дефисами...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

• *Используется ли дефис в слове, где уже есть дефис?*
Да, используется. Теоретически — их количество в слове правилами никак не ограничено.

• *Да и слово **биткойн-кошелёк-то** выглядит слишком уж странно с тремя дефисами...*
Ну... Не с тремя, конечно, а с двумя дефисами. Но именно так и пишется.

**-то** — это словообразовательная единица (постфикс). Она отделяется от мотивирующего слова дефисом и употребляется при подчёркивании или смысловом (интонационном) выделении слова, к которому относится.

У Лопатина (ПАС):

> Недопустимо слитное написание с приставкой или первой частью сложного слова, если вторая часть слова содержит дефис. Слитное написание должно заменяться дефисным, в результате чего возникают написания с двумя дефисами.

Примеры:
вице-премьер-министр, мать-и-мачеха, Ростов-на-Дону, рок-н-ролл, северо-северо-восток, фор-бом-брам-рей, по-честному-то;
*Кстати, **вице-мэр-то** так и сидит* (из статьи).

Похожие вопросы уже обсуждались на форуме:
[Как совмещать в одном слове «по-» и «-то»?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/454194/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%89%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%B8-%D1%82%D0%BE)
[Ставятся ли дефисы, если слово повторяется три раза подряд?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/435686/%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8B-%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4)